# How to refresh a gridview from another class

Tags: flutter, dart

The Animals are displayed in a `Gridview` So when i filter them out by species for example, i want the gridview to refresh when i click on a button from a different class. 
the `_printer(text)` just returns a `List <Animals>`

the main method :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body:
      Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              child: _searchBar(),
            ),    
          _gridDisplay(""),))}
```

```
_gridDisplay(text){
    return Container(
            GridView.count(crossAxisCount: 2,
      children: _printer(text).map((animals)=>InkWell())}
```

Comment: Use callback function to update main grid view https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-communication-between-widgets-f5590230df1e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding a globalkey

```
final homePageKey = GlobalKey<_HomePageState>();
```

and then calling it when i needed the change to occur

```
homePageKey.currentState?.reassemble();
```

Comment: I called homePageKey.currentState?.reassemble(); and set Gridview.builder key:homePageKey  but the gridview did not refresh with my changed data.  can you post the whole code sample for recreation.